# Event Handling in Sabre App

Tags: sabre

I am new to the Sabre Red App plugin development. I am exploring the event handling support in the Red App. Below are my questions:

1) What are the events available. Do we have the event like 'flight booking completed' ?
2) How to register the event handlers for the events ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a combinations of Events that a Red App can subscribe to, mainly tied to Sabre commands in a workflow from a consultant, or specific functions being triggered in the platform (i.e. a Profile being copied to a Trip/PNR being created). When it comes to commands that are utilized to construct the Trip/PNR, these can be any type of command being entered.

One you install the Developer Tools from the Red App SDK on the Eclipse IDE, documentation is added to the default Eclipse Help System for Red Apps.